# Getting ModuleNotFoundError when trying to load Scrapy settings from environment variable

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I am running Scrapy with a Django project and am trying to define the Scrapy settings from outside of the Scrapy project. I am using `get_project_settings()` which looks for the environment variable `SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE`. I have managed to set this to `scraper.crawling.crawling.settings` but when `get_project_settings()` is run, I am shown the error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named crawling`.

This is correct, since `crawling` is a directory and not the module, `settings` is, which I am trying to direct it to. Is anyone able to help me such that `get_project_settings` will correctly find the module `settings`?

Below is the folder structure I am using:

```
├───django-scraper
|   ├───django_scraper
|   |   ├───settings.py
|   │   └───__init__.py
|   ├───scraper
|   │   ├───crawling
|   │   │   └───crawling
|   │   │       ├───spiders
|   │   │       │   └───__init__.py
|   |   |       ├───settings.py   
|   │   │       └───__init__.py
|   │   ├───migrations
|   │   │   └───__init__.py
|   │   ├───templates
|   │   │   └───scraper
|   │   └───__init__.py
```

The following is in my Django `settings.py` so this is set upon starting the server:

`os.environ['SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'scraper.crawling.crawling.settings'`

`get_project_settings()` is called from within `crawler_process.py`, although I don't think the location is an issue since it is looking at the enviornment variable anyway.

My `sys.path` already has `'C:\\Users\\georg\\Django\\django-scraper'` in it, and it appears to access `scraping` fine but then tries to take `scraper.crawling` as a module.

I hope that's enough information - this is my first post so let me know if there's anything else required!

Comment: You have `spiders` folder as well which not reflected in the path.

Comment: My bad, `settings.py` is actually the same tier as `spiders`. I've just amended the diagram to reflect this

Comment: I wonder if not having `scrapy.cfg` may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `__init__.py` file at every **folder level** so python treats it as module, and django will be able to import it.

```
├───django-scraper
|   ├───django_scraper
|   |   └───settings.py
|   │
|   ├───__init__.py
|   ├───scraper
|   │   ├───crawling
|   │   │   └───__init__.py
|   │   │   └───crawling
|   │   │       ├───__init__.py
|   │   │       ├───spiders
|   │   │       ├───settings.py
|   |   |       └───crawler_process.py
```

Comment: Hi Sreevardhan - this was my first thought and I tried adding `__init__.py` to each folder to turn them into packages, but it looks as though it is still trying to treat `crawling` as a module rather than a package.

Comment: can you share your entire folder structure?

Comment: I just updated the question with the full structure. I'm still baffled by this, not sure why it is having issues locating the `settings.py` in `crawling`.